Resources exceeded during query execution since switching from commitment to autoscaling slots
Due to changing business needs we recently changed from a slot commitment to autoscaling slots. Now we get the error "Resources exceeded during query execution: Your project or organization exceeded the maximum disk and memory limit available for shuffle operations. Consider provisioning more slots, reducing query concurrency, or using more efficient logic in this job." on most of our larger jobs. According to the documentation autoscaling slots should provide identical processing capacity as baseline slots from a commitment, the only difference is the billing terms. Why am I seeing this issue and how can I fix it? And yes, I'm aware I can increase the slots, but this is a huge unplanned business expense that I have no explanation for, so I need to dig deeper.

Hi @evam, Were you able to run the larger jobs on using the slot commitments  ? Also, have a look at these documentations link1, link2.

Yes, everything was running smoothly until I switched from 1100 committed slots to 1200 autoscaling slots and the jobs started failing. I now have a 1600 autoscaling slots reservation and it's running smoothly again.

Hi @evam, I have posted a community as per the comments for the sake of community who might encounter this issue in future, do consider accepting and upvoting it as per Stack Overflow guidelines, helping more Stack contributors with their research. Please feel free to edit the answer for any additional information.

I still don't understand why I needed only 1,100 slots before and now I need 1,600...

As commented by @evam, increasing the auto-scaling slot resolution to 1600 resolves the issue, since the auto scaling slots require the maximum slot reservations for running the larger jobs.
You can refer to this documentation for information regarding usage of autoscaling reservations, also check this documentation for resolution of the error you are facing.
Posting the answer as community wiki for the benefit of the community that might encounter this use case in the future. Feel free to edit this answer for additional information.
